# Using arrays and variables in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a simple graphic, that will change, when I change input parameters. I made arrays with input parameters:

```
\def\zamkl{{3,4,4.5,5}}
\def\zamkh{{4,3.5,5,4.5}}
```

then, I'm trying to make variables `myl` and `myh`, which I intend to use later:

```
\pgfmathparse{\zamkl[0]}
\def\myl{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{\zamkh[0]}
\def\myh{\pgfmathresult}
```

but the result is very strange, the figure has size `8x8`, though it should be `6x8`:

[image]

The whole code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zamkl{{3,4,4.5,5}}
\def\zamkh{{4,3.5,5,4.5}}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkl[0]}
\def\myl{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkh[0]}
\def\myh{\pgfmathresult}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,8);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (\myl,0); \node at (B) [below] {$T$};
\coordinate (C) at (2*\myl,0);
\coordinate (D) at (2*\myl,\myh); \node at (D) [left] {$S$};
\coordinate (E) at (2*\myl,2*\myh);
\coordinate (F) at (\myl,2*\myh); \node at (F) [below] {$R$};
\coordinate (G) at (0,2*\myh);
\coordinate (H) at (0,\myh); \node at (H) [right] {$W$};

\draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (E) --(G) -- (A);

\fill (B) circle (4pt);
\fill (D) circle (4pt);
\fill (F) circle (4pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an `\edef` instead of a `\def`.  When you use just a `\def`, the value is set to the macro `\pgfmathresult`, and *not* the *value* of `\pgfmathresult` at the time of the `\def`. The subsequent `pgfmathparse` changes the value of `\pgfmathresult=4` so this is the value that both `\myl` and `\myh` take on once they are evaluated.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zamkl{{3,4,4.5,5}}
\def\zamkh{{4,3.5,5,4.5}}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkl[0]}
\edef\myl{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkh[0]}
\edef\myh{\pgfmathresult}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,8);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (\myl,0); \node at (B) [below] {$T$};
\coordinate (C) at (2*\myl,0);
\coordinate (D) at (2*\myl,\myh); \node at (D) [left] {$S$};
\coordinate (E) at (2*\myl,2*\myh);
\coordinate (F) at (\myl,2*\myh); \node at (F) [below] {$R$};
\coordinate (G) at (0,2*\myh);
\coordinate (H) at (0,\myh); \node at (H) [right] {$W$};

\draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (E) --(G) -- (A);

\fill (B) circle (4pt);
\fill (D) circle (4pt);
\fill (F) circle (4pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Exactly what happens I don't know, but using

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\myl{\zamkl[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myh{\zamkh[0]}
```

instead of the `\def`s works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zamkl{{3,4,4.5,5}}
\def\zamkh{{4,3.5,5,4.5}}


\pgfmathsetmacro\myl{\zamkl[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myh{\zamkh[0]}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,8);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (\myl,0); \node at (B) [below] {$T$};
\coordinate (C) at (2*\myl,0);
\coordinate (D) at (2*\myl,\myh); \node at (D) [left] {$S$};
\coordinate (E) at (2*\myl,2*\myh);
\coordinate (F) at (\myl,2*\myh); \node at (F) [below] {$R$};
\coordinate (G) at (0,2*\myh);
\coordinate (H) at (0,\myh); \node at (H) [right] {$W$};

\draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (E) --(G) -- (A);

\fill (B) circle (4pt);
\fill (D) circle (4pt);
\fill (F) circle (4pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```